# jQuery / JavaScript match the string format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how I can match this 3/28/2014 10:07 format and return false if something like this 3-28-2014 10:07 or this 3/28/2014 10pm gets submitted. Thank you for your help.

JavaScript and jQuery if possible.

Thanks,
Art

Comment: I did'nt post this as an answer because i dont know if it can be done in javascript but maybe you could do some research on REGEX expression with js. I know it can be done in PHP, ASP, C# and another bunch of language maybe there is something similar in js.

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expression to match the string format.

More info on regular expression can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)